# Google maps api request ignores transit mode, why?

Tags: json, google-maps-api-3, request, mode

i would like to know the travel duration between two train stations by train. My request looks like this:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=komagome+station&destination=ueno+station&mode=transit&transit_mode=train&key=++your_api_key++

Unfortunately the resulting json only includes travel directions/information by walking. I'm just clueless here...

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Transit directions are not supported in Japan

from [the FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#transit_directions_countries):

> **In which countries are transit directions available?**
> The Google Maps Directions Service, which includes the Directions API and Distance Matrix API, supports all the transit providers in the transit coverage list, **except for those in Japan**.

Comment: Quite a non-sense for one of the best train networks in the world... I wonder why they can't provide it.